# SQL / SSRS Adding Username to Report use table

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

My scenario is as follows:

If a user runs a report, I want to insert a row into the `ReportUse` table which has 3 fields/columns:

`User, date, reportname`.

Currently I have an `Insert` statement at the end of the report stored procedure which is:

```
INSERT INTO ReportUse (date, reportname)
SELECT GETDATE(), 'StaffReport'
```

This inserts the date and the report name, I am unsure of how to add the username to this, it would be their windows userid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Windows Authentication in the Data Source to connect to the database, just set the *User* column to have a default of `SUSER_NAME()`.

[SUSER_NAME at Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187934.aspx).

Alternatively, you could pass the built-in field `User!UserID` as a parameter to the stored procedure. This will work on SSRS 2005.

[Built in Globals and User References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216.aspx).

**Edit after comment:**

Add a parameter to the stored procedure for the *username* if it doesn't already exist.

Set the value for the parameter to be `=User!UserID`.

In the stored procedure use the *username* parameter in your insert statement.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately its stored credentials that this report uses so the user will be identical each time. Any other ways?

Comment: What about the *User!UserID* option?

Comment: Can the User!UserID be passed in to the insert statement?

Comment: Sure, you can use the *User!UserID* like any other field/expression when passing parameters to the SP in the report. See above for a quick overview.

Comment: Added a hidden parameter within the report with value User!UserID and then used that parameter value and passed it into to the insert statement, worked nicely, thanks :)